# Min and Maxium Age Comparison jQuery

Tags: jquery, logical-operators

Hi I'm new to PHP and I need to make a validation that if the customer age bracket doesn't satisfy the filter then I will disable the question lets say

```
Customer Age Bracket = 40 -44
Question Age Bracket = 18-75
```

So basically the customer is still in the bracket and should be allowed to take the question. Let's say

```
minQuesAge = 18;
maxQuesAge = 75;

minCusAge = 40;
maxCusAge = 44;
```

I have

```
if(parseInt(minCusAge) >= parseInt(minQuesAge) && parseInt(maxCusAge) <= parseInt(maxQuesAge))
{
     console.log("Need to disable");                    
}
```

Why is that I still got Need to disable? Is my Condition correct?

Comment: 40 is greater than 18, and 44 is less than 75, so both conditions are true.

Comment: It looks like you simply have the condition backwards. Your conditions are for when the age is valid, but you're disabling the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions are for when the age is valid, you need to invert it to get the condition for disabling. You can invert a condition with the `!` operator.

```
if(!(parseInt(minCusAge) >= parseInt(minQuesAge) && parseInt(maxCusAge) <= parseInt(maxQuesAge)))
{
     console.log("Need to disable");                    
}
```

You can also use [deMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to invert the parts of the condition.

```
if(parseInt(minCusAge) < parseInt(minQuesAge) || parseInt(maxCusAge) > parseInt(maxQuesAge))
{
     console.log("Need to disable");                    
}
```